# How can you create a SHA-3-256 Hash in Python on The Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sha-3

Having a lot of problems getting an SHA-3 256 Hash working under Python in the Google App Engine.

Speed isn't really the issue just something that is either written in Pure Python or use the third party libraries support by the Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[py-keccak](https://github.com/coruus/py-keccak/blob/master/fips202/keccak.py) uses numpy which is supported by [appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

There is [another one](https://github.com/moshekaplan/python-sha3/blob/master/python_sha3.py) without numpy requirement.